# "a href" tag not closing with JQuery animations

Tags: jquery, html, css

Not sure how else to describe this and I can't include any code because it would be too much.

You can see the problem here:

http://www.findyourgeek.com

If you look on the left side you'll see the headline items that are scrolled through via JQuery.

Now, if you move your mouse over right below that, where it says "Top Stories", you'll see that you can click that as if it's the current active link above.

I've checked my source and all my a href tags are correctly closed so I am really at a loss here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images enclosed in the slideshow links are larger than the container they are housed in. According to Chrome, the images are 620x349 pixels while the container is 569x322 pixels. The links are basically spilling out of the container.

Apply `overflow:hidden` to `div#headlines`. You may need to restyle some of the interior elements as well. Another solution is resizing the images.

Comment: Ah, I set the size of the container but not the images, thanks.  You and Joseph answered at the same time, I'll flip a coin for the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `overflow:hidden` to your `#content #headlines .headlineImage` style rule.

#### home.css Line 96

```
#content #headlines .headlineImage
{
    position:absolute;
    width:565px;
    height:318px;
    border:2px solid #606060;
    -moz-border-radius:14px;
    -webkit-border-radius:14px;
    border-radius:14px;
}
```

should be

```
#content #headlines .headlineImage
{
    position:absolute;
    width:565px;
    height:318px;
    border:2px solid #606060;
    -moz-border-radius:14px;
    -webkit-border-radius:14px;
    border-radius:14px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I set the size of the container but not the images, thanks.  You and Evan above answered at the same time, I'll flip a coin for the accepted answer.

Comment: @Tom actually he got the size part. I only said change the overflow. I think he should get the answer status